# rlc circuit problem

Tags: ac, passive-networks

I'm currently stuck on a homework problem. The question is as follows:

A current generator is supplying a current \$i = 6\sqrt{2}\sin 4000t\$ mA, \$C\$ is adjusted until a minimum voltage, V, appears across the entire RLC circuit. Under these conditions, it is found that V = \$0.3\$ V and the voltage across the capacitor, \$V_c\$ = \$12\$V.

a) Calculate the \$Q\$ of the circuit.

b) Calculate \$C\$, \$L\$ and \$R\$.

Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Welcome, new user! We don't want to ruin your learning experience by doing your homework for you, but many of us here will be more than happy to guide you through it. So, where exactly are you stuck? Can you make any progress at all? Can you show us that you made a decent attempt at solving the problem?

Comment: To expand slightly on @Ricardo's comment, "thanks for your help" type questions do poorly on the Stack Exchange network in general. It's usually better to clearly and explicitly state exactly what you want to know. For example, a good question might be "what is the formula for calculating the Q of the circuit?" (if that is what you are stuck at).

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. How exactly are the resistor, capacitor, and inductor connected? Where is the voltage applied, and where is it measured? Provide a schematic.

Comment: @OlinLathrop it can be nothing else other than a series RLC circuit.

Comment: @Andy: Probably, but this should really have been spelled out and a proper schematic supplied.  It's not only to make sure we know what the OP is talking about, but for us to know that the OP knows what he's talking about.

Answer (score 2):

Clearly it is a series tuned RLC circuit although you haven't said and you are varying C to get resonance - that's the minimum voltage condition that you state.

If that's the minimum voltage then what do you know about the impedances of the inductor and capacitor? Are they: -

1. Incalculable
2. Equal
3. Equal and opposite
4. Zero
5. Infinite
6. Equal to R

One of the these is correct and when you decide on the right one you'll realize that this can be used to directly calculate what value R is.

Given also that C is tuned into resonance and that you have a value for the voltage across it you can then calculate its impedance and, because the frequency is fixed (4000/(2Pi), you can calculate its capacitance.

From here you can infer the inductance using the formula for a tuned circuit: -

\$f_{resonance} = \dfrac{1}{2\pi\sqrt{LC}}\$

Finally, you can use another formula to calculate Q factor - it involves R, L and C and [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RLC_circuit) has a good article.

Comment: Hello Andy, thank you for your in depth reply! I think I have a fundamental error/gap in my understanding somewhere. The current is given by the formula above and I = V/R. So would that current equal 0.3V / total impedance? Now since V = IR, I'm assuming that when the minimum voltage is found, we have a minimum impedance and thus resonance? But it seems as though the current and resistance are independent of I? I'm having trouble with the whole current generator I think.

Comment: Have you decided what the C and L impedances are at resonance as per my list of options or are you still trying to understand the concept of the reactances of C and L in series?

Comment: +1 anyway, even if the OP doesn't deserve the answer.